# Ionic 2 navigate to the root page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How can I navigate to the root page with ionic 2, when  i use this code :

```
 this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');
```

it made the error below

> Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: HomePage

[image: Capture of the error]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.navCtrl.popToRoot();`, It'll pop all views and there's no need to set a new root. This'll also not fire some lifecycle hooks like `ionViewDidLoad()` and `ionViewWillLoad()`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First Check your page component if you have

```
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
```

and because your using lazy page loading you should have this. @ionicpage

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  ....
})
```

last resort is try to resart or reset your ionic serve.
sometimes it happen . and i think its ionic bug.  but no big deal.